# ImportError: No module named html.entities

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, html-entities, importerror

I am new to python. I am using python 2.7.5. I want to write a web crawler. For that I have installed BeautifulSoup 4.3.2. I have installed it using this command(I haven't used pip)

```
python setup.py install
```

I am using eclipse 4.2 with pydev installed. When I try to import this library in my script

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

I am getting this error

```
ImportError: No module named html.entities
```

Please explain me what should I do to rectify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason why are you not using `pip install`, are you on windows, mac, linux ? With that information we could help you faster. Appart from that. This is often a problem when you have more than 1 python installation on your system. Read the following[BeautifulSoup problems after installation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#problems-after-installation).

Also, consider installing using `sudo pip install` if unix, that handles dependecies very well. You could also try on a shell `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` and see if you get the same error you are getting on pydev.

Comment: There is no special reason for not using pip, I just didn't want to go in the hassle of installing it. I am using Eclipse 4.2 on windows 7. I have 2 python installations 2.7 and 3.3. But I have checked that the folder `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\bs4` exists. And I have set path for only python version 2.7.

The link which you have given does not say anything about this error in case of multiple installations.

Also from the command prompt, the same error is coming, so I think its not the problem with pydev.

Comment: would you try installing it using pip ?

Comment: Okay I will try and let you know. Thanks :)

Comment: great, I recommed using pip as much as possible.

Comment: @AbhishekMitruka It's a good practice to mark the correct answer with a check, right next to the vote count.