# beautifulsoup: ImportError: No module named html.entities

Tags: python

I am trying to get this module working on a server, and I am getting the error in the title:

My script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

When I run it:

```
aclark@tycho ~ % python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/builder/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from bs4.element import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 5, in <module>
    from bs4.dammit import EntitySubstitution
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/dammit.py", line 11, in <module>
    from html.entities import codepoint2name
ImportError: No module named html.entities
```

Now, I have seen [ImportError: No module named html.entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20544694/importerror-no-module-named-html-entities)

Which redirects me to
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#problems-after-installation

Based on that:

```
aclark@tycho ~ % sudo pip uninstall BeautifulSoup
Uninstalling BeautifulSoup:
  /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup-3.2.1-py2.7.egg-info
  /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup.py
  /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup.pyc
  /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoupTests.py
  /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoupTests.pyc
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled BeautifulSoup`

`aclark@tycho ~ % sudo pip install BeautifulSoup
Downloading/unpacking BeautifulSoup
  Running setup.py egg_info for package BeautifulSoup

Installing collected packages: BeautifulSoup
  Running setup.py install for BeautifulSoup

Successfully installed BeautifulSoup
Cleaning up...
```

No change in behaviour:

```
aclark@tycho ~ % python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/builder/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from bs4.element import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 5, in <module>
    from bs4.dammit import EntitySubstitution
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/dammit.py", line 11, in <module>
    from html.entities import codepoint2name
ImportError: No module named html.entities
```

I have even removed python3 from the server incase that fixed it, but same problem.

Can anyone point me in a better direction that, uninstall, re-install?

How can I make sure that the code for version 2.7 is installed?

Cheers

Adam

Comment: Module 'html.entities' is available only on Python 3.x. You never be able to solve your problem while you use python 2.x.

Comment: Yes, but I have had BS4 working elsewhere with 2.7, how do I go about making BS4 work properly with 2.7?  Besides, why, if it only works with python3, does it install itself in the python 2.7 site packages?

Comment: I guess what I am saying, is that I don'd care that it wants to import that module, or HTMLParser, BS4 is making that choice on my behalf.

Answer (score 29):

I also met this problem.

At last, I found it's just because I have a file also named "html.py", in the  same directory of the script file.

Therefore, when BeautifulSoup "from html.entities import codepoint2name", it throw exception......

Comment: Thanks for this comment, saved me probably at least an hour of extra work! :)

Comment: The problem also exists when using pytest against a namespace package ending in .html. pytest change the python path during test discovery, see here https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/pythonpath.html

Comment: This absolutely is not the case for me, I have no 'html.py' in the directory.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar problem under different circumstances.

```
pip install future
```

Should do the trick. Check out http://python-future.org/standard_library_imports.html for more information.

Comment: If using conda, `conda install future` did the trick for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when trying to import gtts(I am using python3)

`from gtts import gTTS`

solved it by doing installing html-entities on command line: 
`$ npm install html-entities`

and then import it on the script 
`from html.entities import codepoint2name`

not sure if this is a good way but it works

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the problem using pytest against a namespace package with html inside it (`mycorp.whatever.html`) with the sources and test in the same directory.

Ie this :

```
├── mycorp
│   ├── whatever
│   │   ├── html
│   │   ├── tests
```

Pytest change the python path during test discovery and it add the `html` namespace to your path if the test are mixed with your code, see [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/pythonpath.html)

> pytest will find foo/bar/tests/test_foo.py and realize it is part of a package given that there’s an **init**.py file in the same folder. It will then search upwards until it can find the last folder which still contains an **init**.py file in order to find the package root (in this case foo/). To load the module, it will insert root/ to the front of sys.path (if not there already) in order to load test_foo.py as the module foo.bar.tests.test_foo.

So, in order to fix this problem change your architecture so that tests and sources are not in the same directory.

Ie this :

```
├── tests
├── mycorp
│   ├── whatever
│   │   ├── html
```