# importing BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, import

Error when inmporing beautifulsoup4

```
ImportError: No module named html.entities
```

I tried to install beautifulsoup4 and the version of my python is 3.8.5

I got this error in return when importing bs4

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should check this previous issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372347/beautifulsoup-importerror-no-module-named-html-entities

Comment: ...and this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (if you are new to stackoverflow). how did you install it? what version did you install? what does your import statement look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [beautifulsoup: ImportError: No module named html.entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372347/beautifulsoup-importerror-no-module-named-html-entities)

Comment: As per the duplicate question: do you have a file `html.py` in your working directory?

Answer (score -1):

Try to install your bs4 module properly.
Go to your terminal and type the following commands -

py -m pip uninstall beautifulsoup4
py -m pip install pipwin
py -m pip install beautifulsoup4

and it might work properly after that.

Comment: MIGHT work properly?  Why do you think this is a BeautifulSoup problem?  `html.entities` is a standard library module.  Something is interfering with that.

Comment: It might have gotten corrupted during install, so they could try to reinstall the library...